# how to Disable Schema Introspection in graphql-spqr-spring-boot-starter

Tags: spring-boot, graphql-java, graphql-spqr, graphql-spqr-spring-boot-starter

I have integrated my spring boot application with *graphql-spqr-spring-boot-starter* https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr-spring-boot-starter , I need to find a way on how to disable graphql schema introspection since its a security issue for production.

Answer (score 0):

I am using graphql-spqr 0.9.9 and graphql-spqr-spring-boot-starter 0.0.4, but the code base changed for graphql-spqr 0.10. I'll try to cover both cases, but keep in mind you might have to tweak the code snippets a bit.

In Graphql-spqr-spring-boot starter, `GraphQLSchemaGenerator` is a bean used to generate the `GraphQSchema`. It is defined in `io.leangen.graphql.spqr.spring.autoconfigure.BaseAutoConfiguration` (v0.10) or  `io.leangen.graphql.spqr.spring.autoconfigure.SpqrAutoConfiguration` (v0.9).

You need to provide your own GraphQLSchemaGenerator bean that will set the GraphqlFieldVisibility for the introspection query. According to this issue (cached by google: https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:8VV29F3ovZsJ:https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr/issues/305), there are two different ways to set the field visibility:

#### Graphql-spqr 0.9

```
@Bean
public GraphQLSchemaGenerator graphQLSchemaGenerator(SpqrProperties spqrProperties) {
  GraphQLSchemaGenerator schemaGenerator = new GraphQLSchemaGenerator();

  schemaGenerator.withSchemaProcessors((schemaBuilder, buildContext) -> 
  {
      schemaBuilder.fieldVisibility(new NoIntrospectionGraphqlFieldVisibility());
      return schemaBuilder;
  });

  //Other GraphQLSchemaGenerator configuration
}
```

#### Graphql-spqr 0.10

```
@Bean
public GraphQLSchemaGenerator graphQLSchemaGenerator(SpqrProperties spqrProperties) {
  GraphQLSchemaGenerator schemaGenerator = new GraphQLSchemaGenerator();

  schemaGenerator.withSchemaProcessors((schemaBuilder, buildContext) -> 
  {
    buildContext.codeRegistry.fieldVisibility(NoIntrospectionGraphqlFieldVisibility.NO_INTROSPECTION_FIELD_VISIBILITY);
    return schemaBuilder;
  });

  //Other GraphQLSchemaGenerator configuration
}
```

You can get inspiration from the default implementation to set the GraphQLGenerator properly.

Comment: Overriding the graphql schema  is a simple solution since it has the graphqlschemagenerator object coming with all default settings

Comment: Using this answer requires more change since there are a lot of private variables if i have to override the schema generator, an example could be good?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, there is a bean in SpqrAutoConfiguration class to generateGraphql schema from the generator object

```
@Bean
public GraphQLSchema graphQLSchema(GraphQLSchemaGenerator schemaGenerator) {
schemaGenerator.withSchemaProcessors((schemaBuilder, buildContext) ->
{
 schemaBuilder.fieldVisibility(new NoIntrospectionGraphqlFieldVisibility());
 return schemaBuilder;
});
   return schemaGenerator.generate();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

schemaBuilder.fieldVisibility is Deprecated.

**Graphql-spqr 0.10**

```
    @Bean
    public GraphQLSchema graphQLSchema(GraphQLSchemaGenerator schemaGenerator) {
        schemaGenerator.withSchemaProcessors((schemaBuilder, buildContext) -> {
            schemaBuilder.codeRegistry(
                    buildContext
                            .codeRegistry
                            .fieldVisibility(NoIntrospectionGraphqlFieldVisibility.NO_INTROSPECTION_FIELD_VISIBILITY)
                            .build()
            );
            return schemaBuilder;
        });
        return schemaGenerator.generate();
    }
```