# Disable GraphQL Introspection in graphql-java-tools

Tags: graphql, graphql-java, graphql-schema, graphql-java-tools

I am trying to disable `GraphQL` Introspection in my project and not having much luck with specific framework I am using. Some articles say it can be done in `CcodeRegistry` module but that is a decompiled source which is read only. Has anyone achieved this with the `GraphQL-java-kickstart` framework ?

Below are the dependencies in my pom file:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-java</artifactId>
            <version>${graphql.java.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-java-tools</artifactId>
            <version>${graphql.java.tools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-java-extended-validation</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

### Graphql-java

With graphql-java, you build a `GraphQLSchema` using a `GraphQLSchema.Builder`. You need to set the builder visibility for the introspection field before building to disable the introspection query.

```
GraphQLSchema.Builder builder = GraphQLSchema.newSchema()
                                     .query(query)
                                     .mutation(mutation)
                                     .subscription(subscription)
                                     .additionalTypes(dictionary);

builder.fieldVisibility(NoIntrospectionGraphqlFieldVisibility.NO_INTROSPECTION_FIELD_VISIBILITY);

GraphQLSchema = builder.build();
```

You can use the [graphql-java-tools implementation](https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-java-tools/blob/v5.3.4/src/main/kotlin/com/coxautodev/graphql/tools/SchemaObjects.kt) as a reference.

### Graphql-java-tools

With graphql-java-tools, you build a `SchemaParser`  using a `SchemaParserBuilder`. The SchemaParserBuilder needs a SchemaParserOptions object. When building the SchemaParserOptions, you can enable or disable the introspection query. Here is a very simplified implementation.

```
SchemaParserBuilder builder = new SchemaParserBuilder();
final SchemaParserOptions.Builder optionsBuilder = newOptions();
optionsBuilder.introspectionEnabled(introspectionEnabled);
return builder.options(optionsBuilder.build()).build();
```

You can use the [graphql-spring-boot implementation](https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-spring-boot/blob/a8def2277909d2a94bcef4748cafe9bd03f684e1/graphql-spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/com/oembedler/moon/graphql/boot/GraphQLJavaToolsAutoConfiguration.java#L55) as a reference.

### Graphql-spring-boot

If you are using graphql-spring-boot, according to the graphql-java-tools [README](https://github.com/graphql-java-kickstart/graphql-spring-boot#graphql-java-tools), you can disable the introspection query by setting the `graphql.tools.introspection-enabled` property to false in your application.properties or application.yml file.

```
graphql:
    tools:
        schema-location-pattern: "**/*.graphqls"
        # Enable or disable the introspection query. Disabling it puts your server in contravention of the GraphQL
        # specification and expectations of most clients, so use this option with caution
        introspection-enabled: false
```

### Graphql-spqr

With Graphql-spqr, the idea is the same as in graphql-java: the setting the builder field visibility. See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64520366/how-to-disable-schema-introspection-in-graphql-spqr-spring-boot-starter/64548866#answer-64548866) for how to implement it.

Comment: the issue is that I am not using springboot, the project is based on Google Dagger 2, so has to be done through code.

Comment: Sorry I misread your dependencies. I updated my answer to cover graphql-java and graphql-java-tools.

Comment: @AllirionX Which version for spring boot made it worked because I upgraded to 5.4.1 from 4.0.0 and still it did not work with the given property mentioned. The only change with respect to your answer I have in my code is  I use properties file instead of yml

Comment: @JalajChawla Sorry I don't have a graphql project running. According to my pom.xml file I was using graphql-spring-boot-starter 5.10.0

Comment: Thanks @AllirionX i just figured it out with a new project and it works in a spring boot graphql project for 5.4.1 . The one I tested as an example https://github.com/abhijaykumar/graphql-spring-boot-api

Answer (score 0):

## spring-boot-starter-graphql

In your application.yml

```
graphql:
  schema:
    introspection:
      enabled: false
```

It is implied here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/graphql/GraphQlProperties.Schema.Introspection.html

I am aware that I am not answering the direct question but searches for related queries all end up here.