# How to disbale introspection query in GraphQL-Java?

Tags: java, graphql, graphql-java

I am using GraphQL-Java version:11.0

From [Official GraphQL-Java documenetation](https://www.graphql-java.com/documentation/master/field-visibility) I found that I can disable the introspection query as belwo :

```
GraphQLSchema schema = GraphQLSchema.newSchema()
        .query(StarWarsSchema.queryType)
        .fieldVisibility(NoIntrospectionGraphqlFieldVisibility.NO_INTROSPECTION_FIELD_VISIBILITY)
        .build();
```

Same has been given in [this SO question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64882196/disable-graphql-introspection-in-graphql-java-tools)

But the issue is in above solutions the `fieldVisibility` is available with object returned by `GraphQLSchema.newSchema()`.

I am building the GraphQL schema as below:

```
public GraphQLProvider init(GraphQLResolvers graphQLResolvers) {
        GraphQLSchema graphQLSchema = buildSchema (typeRegistry, runtimeWiring);
        this.graphQL = createInstance (graphQLSchema);
        return this;
    }



private GraphQLSchema buildSchema (TypeDefinitionRegistry typeRegistry, RuntimeWiring runtimeWiring) {
        SchemaGenerator schemaGenerator = new SchemaGenerator();
        return schemaGenerator.makeExecutableSchema(typeRegistry, runtimeWiring);
    }

private GraphQL createInstance (GraphQLSchema graphQLSchema) {
        return GraphQL.newGraphQL(graphQLSchema).build();
    }
```

As you can see in above code, I am not using `GraphQLSchema.newSchema()` anywhere, so I am not able to set the `fieldVisibility` for introspectionQuery, can anyone suggest how can I modify above code to accommodate `fieldVisibility` option?

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `fieldVisibility` option is also available on `RuntimeWiring`, so I just did

```
RuntimeWiring.Builder builder = graphQLResolvers.newRuntimeWiringBuilder();
 builder.fieldVisibility(NoIntrospectionGraphqlFieldVisibility.NO_INTROSPECTION_FIELD_VISIBILITY);
```

Hope it helps someone :)